# Overriding the profiles in creation of profiles - Prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I wanted to add a dropdown list with the profile on creation of profile. I had used override, the dropdown is coming correctly and saved in database also but when editing or viewing it is not making the "dropdown  selected ".

Also so many warnings are coming with undefined name, undefined type. I will share my code :-

### AdminProfilesController.php

```
    class AdminProfilesController extends AdminProfilesControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
        $this->table = 'profile';
        $this->className = 'Profile';
        $this->multishop_context = Shop::CONTEXT_ALL;
        $this->lang = true;
        $this->addRowAction('edit');
        $this->addRowAction('delete');
        $this->addRowActionSkipList('delete', array(1));

        // For add a fields via an override of $fields_form, use $fields_form_override
        if (is_array($this->fields_form_override) && !empty($this->fields_form_override)) {
         $this->fields_form[0]['form']['input'] = array_merge($this->fields_form[0]['form']['input'], $this->fields_form_override);
     }

     $this->bulk_actions = array(
        'delete' => array(
            'text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
            'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?'),
            'icon' => 'icon-trash'
            )
        );

     $this->fields_list = array(
        'id_profile' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('ID'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
            ),
        'name' => array('title' => $this->l('Name'))
        );

     $this->identifier = 'id_profile';

     /* Fetch All Profiles*/
     $admin_levels = Profile::adminLevels();
     foreach ($admin_levels as $row) {         
      $values_access[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id_admin'],
        'name' => $this->l($row['admin_level_name']),
        'label' => $this->l($row['admin_level_name']),
        'val' => $row['id_admin']                                
        );
  }

  $this->fields_form = array(
    'legend' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Profile'),
        'icon' => 'icon-group'
        ),
    'input' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => $this->l('Name'),
            'name' => 'name',
            'required' => true,
            'lang' => true,
            ),
        ),

    $this->fields_form_override = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => $this->l('Access Levels'),
            'name' => 'id_admin',   
                // 'lang' => true,                 
            'col' => '4',                   
            'options' => array(
                'query' => $values_access,
                'id' => 'id',
                'name' => 'name',
                'val' => 'val'
                ),
            ),
        ),


    'submit' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Save'),
        )
    );

  $list_profile = array();
  foreach (Profile::getProfiles($this->context->language->id) as $profil) { 
    $list_profile[] = array('value' => $profil['id_profile'], 'name' => $profil['name']);
}

parent::__construct();
}



}
```

In Classes folder

### Profile.php

```
class Profile extends ProfileCore
{
    /** @var string Name */
    public $name;
    public $id_admin;

    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'profile',
        'primary' => 'id_profile',
        'multilang' => true,
        'fields' => array(
            /* Lang fields */
            'name' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
            'id_admin' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'lang' => true)           
            ),
        );

    /** Fetching Admin Access Levels */
    public static function adminLevels()
    {
        $access_level = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT *  FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'admin_levels');
        return $access_level;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this. I am using prestashop 1.6

profile structure is same as default. profile_lang structure changes
Column         Type 
id_lang        int(10) unsigned
id_profile     int(10) unsigned
name           varchar(128)
id_admin       int(11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using just:

```
$this->fields_form_override = array(
            array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label' => $this->l('Access Levels'),
                'name' => 'id_admin_level',   
                'lang' => true,                 
                'col' => '4',                   
                'options' => array(
                    'query' => $values_access,
                    'id' => 'id',
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'val' => 'val'
                    ),
                ),
        );
```

If you check where it's used:

```
// For add a fields via an override of $fields_form, use $fields_form_override
if (is_array($this->fields_form_override) && !empty($this->fields_form_override)) {
     $this->fields_form[0]['form']['input'] = array_merge($this->fields_form[0]['form']['input'], $this->fields_form_override);
}
```

It will merge the override fields with the $this->fields_form[0]['form']['input'] so the $this->fields_form_override need to be in the same format.

Another solution is to change the name to `$this->fields_form_override` to `$this->fields_form` and instead of `parent::__construct();` use `AdminController::__construct()` to bypass (ignore) the AdminProfile contructor.

Comment: Thank you, the warnings are gone but on editing it is not getting "selected"

Comment: Not sure it helps, but it doesn't need the 'lang' => true. it's a select and not a input multilanguage field.

Comment: Also, what does Profile::adminLevels() return? When creating the array $values_access you have 'id' => $row['id_admin']. Later you use id_admin_level. To be selected the option needs to be true in $fields_value[$input.name] == $option[$input.options.id]

Comment: Profile::adminLevels() return - returns all the $row['id_admin'] and $row['admin_level_name'] into the dropdown. I had changed the code like this

Comment: $this->fields_form_override = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => $this->l('Access Levels'),
            'name' => 'id_admin',   
                // 'lang' => true,                 
            'col' => '4',                   
            'options' => array(
                'query' => $values_access,
                'id' => 'id',
                'name' => 'name',
                'val' => 'val'
                ),
            ),
        ), commented lang

Comment: still not coming

Comment: also, in your profile definition you have id_admin_level as a lang field. can you edit your question and add the table struture for the profile and profile_lang?

Comment: In the profile definition i had changed already to id_admin. Edited the question also

Comment: your profile table and profile class have different properties. in your class you define id_admin_level, but in table they are id_admin. also in your fields_form_override you use the name as id_admin_level. it should be consitent. change all to id_admin or all to id_admin_level. when pretashop get's the values from db, returns id_admin, but your form you use id_admin_level. it won't match.

Comment: I had already changed all to id_admin but still not coming. The edited class - Profile.php is added in the question.

Comment: still  I am not able to fix that issue? can you help?

Comment: i just noticed. your id_admin should be in your profile table, not on the profile_lang. the id_admin is not depedent on the language, is dependent on the id_profile.

Comment: It would have to be a lang field, and for each language, could have a different value. It's not the correct way. And probably wouldn't work with a select, because the only input that is "prepared" for lang field is a text field. You would have to write a custom field.